# Retrofit - Multipart Form with image upload and string array

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, multipartform-data

I am creating an Android app that is using Retrofit 2.0 to send a POST request to a server.  This request will allow the user to create a group which has a name, an array of users, and an image.  I am using a multipart form in this request because the app uploads an image to the server in the form of a file.

This is the presenter, it is given the fields needed for this request.

```
 public void submitGroup(@NonNull final String accessToken,
                        @NonNull final String userId,
                        @NonNull final String groupName,
                        @NonNull final String groupIconUri,
                        @Nullable final String[] members) {


    File file = new File(groupIconUri);


    RequestBody requestOwner =
            RequestBody.create(
                    MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), userId);
    RequestBody requestGroupName =
            RequestBody.create(
                    MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), groupName);
   /**
   * The requestMembers is a String[] containing all member 
   * by id.  This is the field that I am having trouble 
   * making a RequestBody for.
   **/
    RequestBody requestMembers =
            RequestBody.create(
                    MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), 
                                        String.valueOf(members));
    MultipartBody.Part filePart =
            MultipartBody.Part
                    .createFormData("image", file.getName(), 
                           RequestBody.create(
                              MediaType.parse("image/*"), file));


    Log.e(TAG, "accessToken: " + accessToken);
    Log.e(TAG, "userId: " + userId);
    Log.e(TAG, "groupName: " + groupName);
    Log.e(TAG, "groupIconUri: " + groupIconUri);
    // Log.e(TAG, "members: " + members);

    Call<Group> call = service.createGroup(accessToken, 
                                        requestGroupName, 
                                        requestOwner, 
                                        filePart);
    call.enqueue(this);


}
```

Here is the application service class, I have run this and it has worked without including the String[] field for the members.

```
public interface Service {
@Multipart
@POST("/group")
Call<Group> createGroup(@Header("Authorization") String authorization,
                        @Part("name") RequestBody groupName,
                        @Part("owner") RequestBody ownerId,
                        @Part MultipartBody.Part file);
```

Here is the group class that the json is being serialized to:

```
public class Group {
@NonNull
@SerializedName("name")
private String name;
@NonNull
@SerializedName("owner")
private Object owner;
@NonNull
@SerializedName("image")
private String image_name;
@NonNull
@SerializedName("pin")
private int pin;
@NonNull
@SerializedName("created_at")
private Date created_at;
@Nullable
@SerializedName("users")
private Object[] users;
@Nullable
@SerializedName("pending_users")
private Object[] pending_users;

public Group(@NonNull final String name,
             @NonNull final Object owner,
             @Nullable final Object[] users,
             @Nullable final Object[] pending_users,
             @NonNull final String image_name,
             @NonNull final Date created_at,
             @NonNull final int pin) {
    this.name = name;
    this.owner = owner;
    this.users = users;
    this.pending_users = pending_users;
    this.image_name = image_name;
    this.created_at = created_at;
    this.pin = pin;
}

@NonNull
public Date getCreated_at() {
    return created_at;
}
@NonNull
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
@NonNull
public Object getOwner() {
    return owner;
}
@NonNull
public int getPin() {
    return pin;
}

public Object getUsers() {
    return users;
}

public Object getPending_users() {
    return pending_users;
}

public String getImage_name() {
    return image_name;
}
```

My questions are:

1. How can I create send the member String[] as a RequestBody?  I have read that it can be hashmapped, but is that the only way?
2. Is it necessary to have the groupName and ownerId typecasted as RequestBody?  Can I send a @Part simply as a String?